# htaccess and mod_rewrite for IPN redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, paypal-ipn, recurring-billing

I changed my IPN address for Paypal and would like to use htaccess rules to forward the messages to the new handler, however I cannot get it to work.

What is wrong with the below code?
--I want it to redirect requests for /?page=gf_paypal_ipn to https://www.gfreely.com/members/payment/paypal-pro/ipn and it is not working! Ugh! Please help!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?page=gf_paypal_ipn [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.gfreely.com/members/payment/paypal-pro/ipn [P]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on http://statichtml.com/2010/mod-rewrite-baseon-on-query-string.html this should do the trick:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^page=gf_paypal_ipn    [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.gfreely.com/members/payment/paypal-pro/ipn [P]
```